# finger verification using futronic scanner model fs82 using react js with dot net core

Tags: mysql, reactjs, .net-core

I have no idea about finger scanning .but need this problem solved .i am using for solving this problem font end react js and backend dot net core .my client need user finger save to database and filtering stored data using finger .
Is this is possible to implement to web application ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am saveing base64 formate image of finger to database of canvas image . but i can not get data from database using base64 formate images